# Showdown doesn't parse inside html block

Tags: node.js, showdown

I am using [Showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs).

When I run this code:

```js
const showdown = require("showdown")

converter = new showdown.Converter()
const myMarkdownText = '## Some important text'
const myHtmlText = converter.makeHtml(myMarkdownText)
```

I get

```html
<h2 id="someimportanttext">Some important text</h2>
```

which is the expected result.

But when I run this code:

```js
const showdown = require("showdown")

converter = new showdown.Converter()
const myMarkdownText = '<div markdown = "1"> ## Some important text </div>'
const myHtmlText = converter.makeHtml(myMarkdownText)
```

I get

```html
<div markdown = "1"><p>## Some important text </p></div>
```

Which means that Showdown didn't parse the stuff inside the html div.

Any help on how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but for future reference:

To enable parsing of markdown inside HTML tags you have to put `markdown="1"` as a property on the HTML tag like:

```
<div markdown="1"># I will be parsed</div>
```

There is more information in the [documentation](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown/wiki/Showdown%27s-Markdown-syntax#handling-html-in-markdown-documents)

Answer (score 0):

After reading the Showdown documentation (https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown#valid-options) my conclusion is that you should probably enable the `backslashEscapesHTMLTags` option and backslash the html tags.

Comment: It didn't work. I don't think this option has to do with converting markdown to html, but with converting html to markdown (how are escape tags inside the html treated)

Comment: @MatanLivne - did you ever figure this out? It's driving me mad.